# Ruined portal Nether in overworld

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

So, I am working on a datapack, and I came across this ruined portal (in the Overworld). However, this specific portal was of the Nether variant (blackstone instead of stone). What are the conditions for the spawning of a nether ruined portal? I am not sure how but I'm assuming its something temperature related?

Edit: according to the structure file, it should only spawn in biomes tagged with the ability to spawn the structure which I did NOT edit. I assume by default it does not include rivers.

[image]

Comment: was your datapack editing any of the world generation settings? Or loading some world gen structures manually? Because if not, this is just a normal occurrence of ruined portals spawning in a world.

Comment: That is a nether ruined portal (notice the blackstone), so it should not be generating in the overworld

Comment: You are correct, my bad.